# np.arange returns <Response 200> instead of value

Tags: python, numpy, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a script that scrapes the text of multiple webpages with slightly differing URLs. I want to go through the pages with an np.arange function that inserts a string into the URL. But there must be something wrong with the URL the script is composing. In the document, that stores the scraped text, it scrapes just messages like "this site does not exist anymore".  The steps I have taken to come closer to the solution are detailed below. Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import datetime

from time import sleep
from random import randint

datum = datetime.datetime.now()

pages = np.arange(1, 20, 1)

datum_jetzt =  datum.strftime("%Y") + "-" + datum.strftime("%m") + "-" + datum.strftime("%d") 

url = "https://www.shabex.ch/pub/" + datum_jetzt + "/index-"

results = requests.get(url)

file_name = "" + datum.strftime("%Y") + "-" + datum.strftime("%m") + "-" + datum.strftime("%d") + "-index.htm"

for page in pages:

    page = requests.get("https://www.shabex.ch/pub/" + datum_jetzt + "/index-" + str(page) + ".htm")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    texte = soup.get_text()

    sleep(randint(2,5))

    f = open(file_name, "a")

    f.write(texte)

    f.close
```

I found that if I find enter `print("https://www.shabex.ch/pub/" + datum_jetzt + "/index-" + str(page) + ".htm")` in the console, I get `https://www.shabex.ch/pub/2020-05-18/index-<Response [200]>.htm`. So the np.arange function returns the response of the webserver instead of the value I seek.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You're assigning to the variable `page` when you already have a for-loop variable `page`. Change the one in the for loop to `results` like you have above.

Comment: That being said, the use of numpy makes no sense at all here